How to run just 1 statement in Google Bigquery UI
I like to write multiple statements in the same query, because I want to check multiple things. I'm new to BigQuery and so far the only way I can get 1 statement to run is via highlighting the whole thing, and sometimes it can be long. Snowflake has a neat function to only run the statement where the cursor is at. Do you know if BigQuery has something equivalent?

You can select the statement and click "Run" or hit Control+Enter

When using BigQuery Studio, you can enter multiple statements.  If you want to run just one of those statement, you can use your mouse/cursor and select just the statement you want to run and then run it.  I believe that you fully grasp that.  Your question appears to be looking for a simpler story ... for example, moving your mouse cursor into the statement to be executed and somehow asking "Please parse the SQL text and look for the SQL statement in which my cursor is located.  Please logically extract that and run it by itself".  To the best of my knowledged, BigQuery doesn't have that capability.  This might be a great candidate to raise a feature request to Google to have it examined for possible future inclusion.
In the interim, let me offer an additional notion.  BigQuery Studio provides query pages that I believe you are using to enter/submit BigQuery SQL.  An alternative is to leverage the Python Notebooks also found in BigQuery Studio.  Within a notebook, you can create "cells" that are discrete pieces of function to execute.  Instead of having multiple statements in a Query page, we might be able to have individual statements in a notebook cells.  Similar to the query page, you can save notebooks (as opposed to saving queries).
One doesn't have to write just python in the notebook.  One can use the notebook "magic" command called %%bigquery and simply enter SQL just as you would in BigQuery studio.  With a cell per SQL statement, you can now pick and choose which statements to execute.

Yes you correctly understand what I'm thinking of - Snowsight in Snowflake has that feature and it's very very convenient for investigation type of tasks. But well, it is what it is. I will explore the python notebooks options. thanks.
